# How to set static IP address on the FreeBSD machine?

Tags: networking, freebsd, static-ip

I have a FreeBSD machine running on a virtual machine. I am using SUN Virtual Box.
I need to set static IP address to this machine. So that I can access this machine.
Is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

in /etc/rc.conf:

```
ifconfig_em0="inet 192.168.0.254 netmask 255.255.255.0"
defaultrouter="192.168.0.1"
```

192.168.0.254 -- the machine IP, 192.168.0.1 -- gateway
These settings in rc.conf are looked up in the boot process.
If you'd like to set ip manually, run:

```
ifconfig em0 inet 192.168.0.254 netmask 255.255.255.0
route delete default; route add default 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: It can also be done without directly editing the file, via `sysrc ifconfig_em0=inet 192.168.0.254 netmask 255.255.255.0. `sysrc` is a built-in tool in FreeBSD specifically designed to add/remove entries from the `/etc/rc.conf` file.

Comment: I am using FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE-p10 and when I run the command I am getting unknown variable error.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do the same thing:

- run "sysinstall" as root
- "configure"
- "networking"
- "interfaces"
- Now choose you interface and configure it.

Comment: There is no `sysinstall` on FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE